# How to get a package const value by name using reflect?

Tags: reflection, go

It's a package having some constants.

```
package object

type Languaege int

const (
    Javascript Languaege = iota
    C
    Cpp
    Shell
)
```

//========================================

how can i get the value of a type Language if I know its name?

```
package main
func GetConstByName(name String) {
    ....
}
lang := GetConstByName("Shell")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do it except by hand if you want `Language` to remain a `const` integer type.

Here is what I would do - make Language implement [Stringer](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) which means you can print it too. You can then invert `languageMap` to turn language strings into `Language`

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/_6TTwGDJRX)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Language int

const (
    Javascript Language = iota
    C
    Cpp
    Shell
)

var languageMap = map[Language]string{
    Javascript: "Javascript",
    C:          "C",
    Cpp:        "Cpp",
    Shell:      "Shell",
}

func (l Language) String() string {
    return languageMap[l]
}

var languageMapReverse map[string]Language

func NewLanguage(languageName string) Language {
    if languageMapReverse == nil {
        languageMapReverse = make(map[string]Language)
        for l, name := range languageMap {
            languageMapReverse[name] = l
        }
    }
    return languageMapReverse[languageName]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("C is %d: %s: %d\n", C, C, NewLanguage("C"))
    fmt.Printf("Shell is %d: %s: %d\n", Shell, Shell, NewLanguage("Shell"))
}
```

This outputs

```
C is 1: C: 1
Shell is 3: Shell: 3
```

Answer (score -4):

You're trying to abuse reflection. In this case, fortunately for you, it will not work. If you want to *map* string keys to some associated values then use a `map[string]someValueType` instead.

Comment: How do you know if he's trying to abuse reflection?